# Salvar em arquivo txt e recuperar em uma comboBox

Tags: c#, txt

Preciso fazer o seguinte:

1. Cadastrar um cliente no formulário.
2. Salvar o `nome` dos clientes que forem cadastrando em um arquivo txt no computador, exemplo:

   - João
   - Marcos
   - Willian
3. Carregar esses nomes em uma `comboBox` em outro formulário.

Código do formulário do cliente, até o momento consegui fazer criar o arquivo txt e colocar os nomes, só não entendi como faço para mostrar na comboBox agora.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ProjetoFinal
{
    public partial class frmCadastroClientes : Form
    {
        int i = 0;
        int poc;

        public frmCadastroClientes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            dgvClientes.Rows.Add(i, txtNome.Text, txtEnd.Text, txtCidade.Text, txtEstado.Text, maskFone.Text, txtEmail.Text);


            //Salvar clientes no TXT
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbClientes.txt", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(txtNome.Text);
        }


                /**
                String nome = txtNome.Text;
                frmOrdemServico os = new frmOrdemServico();
                os.MostrarClientes(nome);




                int tamanho = 50;
                string[] nomes = new string[tamanho];


                for(int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
                {

                }
                **/



                txtNome.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtEstado.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";

            btnEditar.Enabled = true;
            btnExcluir.Enabled = true;
            btnGravar.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnLimpar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtEstado.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";

            btnGravar.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            poc = dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index;

            txtNome.Text = dgvClientes[1, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEnd.Text = dgvClientes[2, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtCidade.Text = dgvClientes[3, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEstado.Text = dgvClientes[4, poc].Value.ToString();
            maskFone.Text = dgvClientes[5, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dgvClientes[6, poc].Value.ToString();


            btnGravar.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvClientes[1, poc].Value = txtNome.Text;
            dgvClientes[2, poc].Value = txtEnd.Text;
            dgvClientes[3, poc].Value = txtCidade.Text;
            dgvClientes[4, poc].Value = txtEstado.Text;
            dgvClientes[5, poc].Value = maskFone.Text;
            dgvClientes[6, poc].Value = txtEmail.Text;

            MessageBox.Show("Cliente número: " + i + " Alterado!");
        }

        private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (poc < 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma linha selecionada ou não há o que excluir!");
            else
                dgvClientes.Rows.RemoveAt(poc);
        }

        private void frmCadastroClientes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnNovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnGravar.Enabled = true;
            btnExcluir.Enabled = false;
            btnEditar.Enabled = false;

            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtEstado.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ler o arquivo a cada alteração que fizer nele e carregar seu [comboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964574/2740371) com os dados que tem nele.

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbClientes.txt");
foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
{
   string[] nomes = line.Split(',');
   comboBox1.Items.Add(nomes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Coloco este código no load do formulário onde vai carregar a `comboBox`?

Comment: Funcionou, isso mesmo, se puder explicar o que está acontecendo neste código que postou eu agradeço!!

Comment: Não esqueça de limpar o combo antes de uma nova leitura! rsrs

Comment: @rovannLinhalis porque? Eu só estou adicionando direito.. só coloquei esse código e boa

Comment: caso você venha a ler o arquivo depois de uma possível alteração nele... durante a execução do programa e não no load do form. aí você tem que limpar os itens antes, se não, serão duplicados. Se está lendo só uma vez, sem não esquenta com isso

Comment: @RovannLinhalis verdade acabei de testar isso está duplicando todos rs. posso colocar o que antes do load então tentei: `cbClients.Items.Clear()` não funcionou

Comment: Exata, você tera duplicação dos dados se não limpa ele a cada alteração... use o comboBox1.Items.Clear()

Comment: você esta escrevendo duas vezes no mesmo arquivo ?

Comment: coloca `cbClients.Items.Clear()` antes do `ReadAllLines` ou do `foreach`

Comment: eu vi um tutorial que o cara pediu pra fazer aquele código porque um era pra escrever o outro pulava linha

Comment: @RovannLinhalis duplica da mesma forma, acho que o erro tá na hora de gravar no txt

Comment: é...vi que voce colocou o atributo `append` como true, talvez tenha que revisar isso aí

Comment: Achei onde tava o erro vou alterar, só precisa deixar uma vez o `using`