# Carregar dois campos de um DataGrid usando um arquivo txt

Tags: c#, datagridview, txt

Como posso fazer isso, veja o que tenho até o momento:

DataGrid, preciso carregar o `comboBox` e o `valor unitário` com valores que salvei previamente em um `txt`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Botão gravar produtos, gravar o nome - preço

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            double vtotal = 0;
            vtotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtVlrVenda.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtQntd.Text);

            dgvProdutos.Rows.Add(i, txtNome.Text, txtFornecedor.Text, maskCNPJ.Text, txtEnd.Text, txtCidade.Text, txtUF.Text, maskFone.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtNfe.Text, txtVlrVenda.Text, txtQntd.Text, vtotal);


            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(txtNome.Text + " - " + txtVlrVenda.Text);
            }


            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtFornecedor.Text = "";
            maskCNPJ.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtUF.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtNfe.Text = "";
            txtVlrVenda.Text = "";
            txtQntd.Text = "";

            btnEditar.Enabled = true;
            btnExcluir.Enabled = true;
            btnGravar.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Neste tópico anterior: [Salvar em txt e recuperar em uma comboBox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249534/salvar-em-arquivo-txt-e-recuperar-em-uma-combobox) me ensinaram carregar a `comboBox`, porém neste caso não entendi como faço para acessar a coluna que criei dentro do DataGrid. O código até o momento está assim:

```
private void frmOrdemServico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbClientes.txt");
            cbClientes.Items.Clear(); // limpar para não duplicar valores
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] nomes = line.Split(',');
                cbClientes.Items.Add(nomes[0]);
            }


            string[] Produtos = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt");
            foreach (var line in Produtos)
            {
                string[] produtos = line.Split('-');
                dgvProdutos. //comboBox que irá carregar os produtos
                dgvProdutos. //txtBox que irá mostrar o valor de cada produto seleciona, ja cadastrado no txt
            }
        }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar com algo? Eu até achei este site que ensina recuperar valores que estão concatenados mas pra por no DataGrid não fala nada: [Gravando e Lendo dados em arquivo texto com Csharp](http://satellasoft.com/?materia=gravando-e-lendo-dados-em-arquivo-texto-com-csharp)

Comment: Pergunta: por que você tá usando um TXT pra operações tão complexas?

Comment: Resposta: Porque estava a usar banco de dados e não consegui, ai me parece mais viável desta forma `txt`, visto que só irei apresentar para os professores e a matérias não cobra banco de dados no máximo usando arquivos de texto mesmo. Eu só quero mostrar ali e boa não vai gravar mais nada, só pra mostrar como o sistema funciona fluxo passa etc.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é utilizar um *DataTable* para o serviço.

Adicione ao seu projeto um *DataTable* com duas colunas, 'Produto' e 'Preço'

```
public DataTable produtos = new DataTable() { Columns = { new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Produto" }, new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Preço" } } };
```

preencha este DataTable com os dados do arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
public static void lerProdutos()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns[0];
    string[] Produtos = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt");
    foreach (var line in Produtos)
    {
        string[] Dados = line.Split('-');
        produtos.Rows.Add(Dados[0], Dados[1]);
        comboBox.Items.Add(Dados[0]);
    }
}
```

No seu DataGridView, Adicione o evento *EditingControlShowing* que ira verificar se o valor do *comboBox* foi alterado

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= valorModificado;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += valorModificado;
        }
    }
```

e o evento que ira buscar o preço do produto:

```
private void valorModificado(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns[0];

        DataRow[] rows = produtos.Select($"Produto = '{comboBox.ValueMember}'");
        string valor = rows[0][0].ToString();
        comboBox.ValueMember = rows[0][0].ToString();
    }
```